# How to increase image's height and width without stretching it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have a div section of width 1000px and 290 px height.if i upload image of width 500px and height 400px,and increase height and width from code,here is my code sample,it get stretch the image

```
  var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        //Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);

        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        //Bitmap bmpcrop = bmpImage.Clone(imageRectangle, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
        //return (Image)bmpcrop;
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(img, imageRectangle);
        MemoryStream stram = new MemoryStream();
        thumbnailImg.Save(stram, img.RawFormat);
        byte[] imagebytes = stram.ToArray();
        return imagebytes;
```

Comment: You can't make it bigger without stretching it. Are you asking how to keep its proportions the same?

Comment: yes i want to make it fit the screen and it should not stretched.

Comment: Do you have any idea @nnnnnn?

Comment: only way you can do this is to have an image bigger than you require and then make it smaller, if you have a small image and try to make it bigger, it will stretch

Answer (score 0):

To resize an image ensuring that it is the same proportions, the ratio of the initial height x width (h x w) will have to be the same as the final h x w.

In your case your initial ratio is 500:400 while the final is 1000:290.

From 500:400, you can make it 1000:800, making it 2x bigger. Here the initial ratio is the same as the final ratio.

However, this won't fit the width of your specified div.

The other way is to reduce the width to 290, which means to proportionally reduce the height, you have to make the height be reduced by a factor of (1000 * (290/400)) which will be less than 1000.

So the only way is to either change your initial picture dimensions or your div dimensions if you want a perfect fit.